# Matlab Dual GPU memory usage

Tags: matlab, matrix, multi-gpu

I have a Dual GPU card named Titan Z. I have Matlab 2016a trying to solve a sparse `Ax=b` equation set for different '`b`' values. Titan Z has two GPUs and 6 GB ram for each gpu

Here is the problem.

1. If I solve a `Ax=b` problem on 1 GPU, let's say a '`A`' matrix size of
   2GB, Matlab copies this matrix to each GPU's vram. GPU-Z reports
   that each GPU has 2 GB of data and only 1 GPU is working
2. If I solve two `Ax=b` problem on 2 GPU, let's say '`A`' matrix size of 2GB, Matlab again copies this matrix to each GPU's vram twice. Now GPU-Z reports that each GPU has 4GB of data and two GPU is working simultaneously.
3. If I try to solve a '4GB' problem simultaneously Nvidia driver **crashes** due to insufficient Vram. But I can solve it on one GPU. not on 2 GPU simultaneously.

Problem is Matlab copies those matrices twice, when it is not needed, more interestingly, it does this when two GPUs uses exact same '`A`' matrix but different '`b`' vectors.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you share your code? Are you using `spmd` or similar?

Comment: It is pretty simply actually. I'm using gpuArray to allocate and transfer and after that I use the parfor loop (i=1:2) to solve the equation set. on GPU.

Comment: So you are not building the `gpuArray` inside the `parfor` loop? What happens if you do build the `gpuArray`s inside `parfor`?

Comment: I also tried building it inside. I even called gpuDevice inside make sure it goes to correct GPU. I tried many other things. I'm suspecting that Nvidia driver mirrors any data goes to  one GPU since this is a dual GPU card. Next step I will plug in another GPU to see if it copies it to the third one too. Again I must remind you that both GPU's must have same matrix but different vector `b`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late reply to my own question but here is the solution.
Disabling multi-GPU mode in Nvidia Control Panel solved the problem.
Basically it disables the sli and gpus can run independently. It was simple as that.